# Right Click Mouse Warning

Tags: mouse, notification, tap-to-click

does anyone have any idea how to disable this notification from popping up every time I click a mouse button (doesn't matter if it's a right or left click, it still comes up)? It is very annoying and I cannot find any documentation on the darn thing. I am using a Microsoft Surface with type cover on the latest Gnome 3 Ubuntu.

pop up:

[image]

::EDIT::
I have been searching more about this with no luck yet, but could this be something with the mouse setting and the surface type cover? Something with Synaptic drivers...??